# Strings - Stack and heap in java

Tags: java, string

I know that Strings are stored on the heap and the reference to them is stored on the stack. So in the code below `one` would point to `"John"` on the heap from the stack and likewise `two` would point to `"Smith"` on the heap from the stack.

So what happens when i do `one = two`? 
Does `one` now point to where `two` points to because `two` contains a reference to a point on the heap or does it change the `"John"` on the heap to `"Smith"`?

```
String one;
one = "John";
String two = "Smith"
one = two;
```

Comment: Why would it keep 2 versions of the same exact string if it doesn't have to?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with what is on the stack and what is on the heap. You could make it clearer by removing references to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now `one`  will point to the `two` .
Since all string are immutable then when they are created then they are stored in heap and referenced by variable but when you make or assign new variable to same string then it will not explicitly create new string but just reference to same string which is in `heap`
[image]

from above picture you can easily understand the concept of immutability.
for reference [Where does java reference variable stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623563/where-does-java-reference-variable-stored)

Comment: And these references are stored on the stack?

Comment: @user3562135 check the link for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `one` now points to the same place as `two`. The original string on the heap `"John"` becomes garbage and is subject to garbage collection.

It's not possible to see in this example because `String` is immutable, but if these were mutable data structures such as an `ArrayList`, then modifying the object through `one` would make the same change visible through `two`, because they point to the same object.